# Slide não preenche a tela inteira com bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando colocar um slide no meu site, porém quando eu indexo o **Bootstrap 4** na página, o slide não ficar com a tela cheia (não preenche a tela), quando não indexo o slide roda certinho preenche toda a tela como e quero, mas se eu não usar o Bootstrap não vou conseguir adicionar certos elementos na página que necessitam dele, segue o código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SLIDER DEVMEAN</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>
<body>



  <div class="container slide-principal">       
        <!-- INICIO DO SLIDER -->
        <section class="slider">
            <div class="slider_box">

                <article class="slider_item active"  slider-bg="imagens/casa1.jpg">
                    <div class="slider_content">
                        <h1>1 TITULO DO SLIDE SEMÂNTICO</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos tempore accusantium mollitia dignissimos quidem explicabo, recusandae. Assumenda, nemo voluptatum accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="slider_item" slider-bg="images/slide2.jpg">
                    <div class="slider_content">
                        <h1>2 JAVASCRIPT NA VEIA</h1>
                        <p>Desenvolvemos aplicativos web para as necessidades do seu negócio.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="slider_item" slider-bg="images/slide3.jpg">
                    <div class="slider_content">
                        <h1>3 UM TITULO QUALQUER</h1>
                        <p>Somos apaixonados pelo que fazemos, vamos introduzir e fixar a imagem de sua empresa destacando seus produtos e serviços na Internet, com muito talento, tecnologia e comprometimento.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

            </div>
            <div class="slider-prev"><</div>
            <div class="slider-next">></div>
        </section>
        <!-- FIM DO SLIDER -->

    </div>
```

Comment: Sol se a resposta te serviu, basta clicar no icone abaixo das setinhas na esquerda no inicio da minha resposta para marca como aceita. Assim o StackOverflow fica melhor organizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jovem o próprio Bootstrap4 tem o seu componente de Slider (carrocel) vc pode ler sobre ele e ver a documentação completa aqui: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Veja um exemplo do modelo padrão do Bootstrap 4 funcionando. As vezes ele te atende e vc não precisa usar outro plugin que pode conflitar como as demais Classes e JavaScripts originais do BS4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=
 content=
>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    .slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    

        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=777&amp;fg=555&amp;text=First slide" alt="First slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_162016ba554%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_162016ba554%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h3>First slide label</h3>
                      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=666&amp;fg=444&amp;text=Second slide" alt="Second slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_162016ba556%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_162016ba556%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=555&amp;fg=333&amp;text=Third slide" alt="Third slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_162016ba557%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_162016ba557%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**OBS:** Esse Slider ocupa a tela inteira, é responsivo, porém repare no Snippet acima com o código que para ele funcionar, além de importar os .CSS vc também precisa importas o jQuery e os .JS padrão do BS4

Comment: Acabei de ler a documentação do bootstrap me salvou sua resposta, eu já não sabia mais onde procurar, não sabia da função do carrosel obrigada.

Comment: Sol que bom que ajudou, se vc puder marcar minha resposta como aceita eu agradeço muito :)

Comment: Marquei como aceita :)